# Is opening a blog, publishing technological/educational content on it and earning money via blogger earning methods like AdSense legal?

Tags: copyright, criminal-law, internet, software, licensing

I am planning to open a blog website and publish `technology-based` educational content as articles in Turkish language on it. Topics I'll cover are Microsoft and Linux system administration, cyber security, software, hardware, web, mobile, desktop applications with their usage and much more things like this.

More clearly, for example, I'll post:

- What is Active Directory and How to Install it on Windows version x.x.x?
- How to Configure DNS Server on Ubuntu?
- What should be considered for cyber security?
- What are social engineering methods and how to implement them?
- How to run JavaScript code in C# App? (or it can be complete JavaScript tutorial)
- What are the differences between USB 2.0 and 3.0?
- How to change desktop wallpaper on Windows 10?
- How to change screen brightness on IOS version x.x.x?
- How to use TeamViewer?

As you guess, for all of these, I need `tons of` programs, software, tools like VMware, virtual machines like Kali Linux, Ubuntu, Windows Server 2012 or 2016, Windows 8 or 10 and screenshots.

I am planning to use `trial, free or non-commercial` version of these for preparing my content. My future plan is adding English articles and video contents to my blog. However, I don't know using the tools, software and programs the way I mentioned with making money purpose is legal.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: And so the question here is whether you can use software under a non-commercial license for the purpose of learning about its use and taking screenshot of it in operation, which you are in turn doing for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Legal unless you violate copyright.

Screenshots will probably be fair use. The manuals/how-tos need to be your originals, not copies from anywhere.

Comment: Can you give more detail with examples? Which states violates copyright?

Comment: Whether copyright is violated can't be told from your list. It depends on the actual content, specifically whether it was copied from anywhere or written from scratch.